# Plugin Development - Using Classes in single-{CPT}.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in which I am using a class for retrieving post data in `plugin-folder > includes > PostData.php` and I have a single page for custom post type `plugin-folder > single-look.php` Now i want to use that class in single file.I am doing it right below.

```
get_header();

$id = get_the_ID();

$postdata = new PostData($id);
```

But i am getting `Fatal Error : : Class 'PostData' not found in .....on line 7`. I need to know how i can link between this two??Obviously that class was instantiated in plugin init and that function is working fine with some other filters.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `get_post` it will retrieve the post data check below code.

```
get_header();
$id = get_the_ID();
$postdata = get_post($id);
```

Comment: But my PostData is class made by me with further optimization

Comment: share your class file which you are using.